# Retrieveing status code from a response in java

Tags: java, http-response-codes

How to retrieve a response code for an error page? For successful page I am using `getresponsecode` method. But for an error page, which method I have to use to get a status code of a response of web application?

Answer (score 2):

[`HttpServletResponse.getStatus()`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getStatus()) is the one you're looking for. It is not just for error pages, it is for every servlet responses.

The `HttpServletResponse` class contains constants for the possible values, e.g.

- `HttpServletResponse.SC_OK` for success (200)
- `HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST` for indicating a bad request (400)

Comment: it showing HttpServletResponse can not be resolved.help me to fix this

Comment: @Sakthivel Are you even using Java Servlet? Or Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

`httpServletResponse.getStatus()` will give you an int value which represents the status code. 
Open `HttpServletResponse` class an you ll find the list of the possible status codes